# Is there any Sqlite select query for getting two tables result?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a table named as Timings that contains the following things

```
Id   Team1     Team2           MD          MT
1    Name1     Name2    26/07/2013   10.00
2    Name3     Name4    26/07/2013   11.00
```

another table called Players

```
Id     Name    Email  
Name1  Naveen  email  
Name2  Bos     email
Name3  Sharath email
Name4  mohan   email
```

and i need result like this, Is it possible to get a result in a single query?

```
MD          MT      PlayerName1  playername2
26/07/2013  10.00   Naveen       Bos
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843202/how-do-i-combine-data-from-two-separate-tables-into-a-single-cursor/17843427#17843427

Comment: Use JOIN and get it done

Comment: Does `id` really have the value `Name3` on two rows?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That's my mistake sorry

Answer (score 2):

Try double `join` as below

```
select T.MD,T.MT,P1.Name as PlayerName1, P2.Name as playername2 
from Timings T
join Players P1 on P1.Id = T.Team1
join Players P2 on P2.Id = T.Team2
```